# Two switches and two light bulbs at home

Tags: home-installation

I want to wire two light bulbs with two switches so that one (only one at a time) of them is always on. This is the idea:

| Switch 1 | Switch 2 | Light bulb 1 | Light bulb 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Up | Up | On | Off |
| Up | Down | Off | On |
| Down | Up | Off | On |
| Down | Down | On | Off |

In other words, when both switches are in the same position, light 1 is on, and when they are in different positions, light 2 is on.
What kind of switches do I have to buy and what would the wiring look like?

Comment: This is homework, not _home-installation_. What have you come up so far, and where are you stuck?

Comment: AC/DC, Which Voltage, Current requirements?

Comment: I can think of a way with 2 "4-way switches" and no relays, but it will violate the building code due to separating hot and neutral. Is this a theoretical question or do you actually want it in your house?

Comment: @Seir I'm stuck at the part where I don't know where to buy the switches, or if they even sell them.

Comment: @HandyHowie your typical home AC 220V 10A circuit

Answer (score 2):

Two DPDT switches would be required.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flyW3u.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A solution using standard 2-way switches and a relay.*

- When LAMP1 is on the relay is energised and LAMP2 is disconnected (off).
- When LAMP1 is off the relay is deenergised and LAMP2 is powered (on).

The relay coil needs to be AC type and match your mains voltage. If using incandescent lamps the contact ratings should be 5 × the lamp current to allow for surge current due to cold filament. Otherwise contact ratings should match the load current and voltage.

Answer (score -3):

What you describe is a XNOR gate for light bulb 1 and a XOR gate for light bulb 2. You will need power mosfet due to the high voltage(230V).

Comment: Mosfets are not suitable for switching mains voltage AC.

Comment: The question doesn't actually say it's 230 V AC, just 'at home' - that does imply AC mains though.

Comment: @nekomatic No, the question doesn't, but this answer says 230V. I did assume the AC part, as I have to assume no one has 230V DC lights at home.